Advice on how to get an approximate symbolic expression for nasty limit-integral
I have a fairly nasty integral-limit expression that I need to resolve and was hoping for some advice on the best practice to getting a solution. I have the following functions
\begin{gather*}
w(\beta,z) = \frac{1}{\int_0^\beta \sqrt{\frac{24z \cdot t^3 - 28z \cdot t^2 + 2z (5-z)\cdot t - \
z}{128\cdot t^6 - 256 \cdot t^5 + 32(6+z)\cdot t^4 - 16(4+3z)\cdot \
t^3 + 8(1+32z) \cdot t^2 - 4z \cdot t}} dt}\\
f(z) = \int_0^{1/2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{ -256 \cdot t^4 + 256 \cdot t^3 - 64(1+z) \cdot t^2 + \
32z\cdot t}} dt
\end{gather*}
And I need to find the function
$$
g(z) = \lim_{\beta\to1/2^{-}} \frac{w(\beta,z)}{\int_{c_{-}}^{c_{+}} w(\beta,z) f(z) dz} 
$$
This is all; assuming that $z>1/4$. I know that $g(z)$ should be strictly nonnegative from $c_{-}\leq z \leq c_{+}$ and should not be zero everywhere. I've tried various forms of AsymptoticIntegrate for the integrals of t. But no matter what I do I keep getting $g(z) = 0$.
I've done the following
h[t_,z_]=Sqrt[(-z-28 t^2 z+24 t^3 z-2 t (-5+z) z)/(-256 t^5+128 t^6-4 t z+32 t^4 (6+z)-16 t^3 (4+3 z)+t^2 (8+24 z))]
leftFunc[t_,z_] = FullSimplify[Asymptotic[h[Abs[t], z], {t, 0, 4}, Assumptions -> z > 0 && t > 0], Assumptions -> z > 0 && t > 0]
rightFunc[t_,z_] = FullSimplify[Asymptotic[h[-Abs[t - 1/2] + 1/2, z], {t, 1/2, 4},Assumptions -> z > 0 && t < 1/2], Assumptions -> z > 0 && t < 1/2]
w[t_,z_] = 1/(FullSimplify[Integrate[rightFunc[t, z], t] - Integrate[rightFunc[tt, z], tt] /. {tt -> 1/4} + Integrate[leftFunc[tt, z], tt] /. {tt -> 1/4} - Integrate[leftFunc[tt, z], tt] /. {tt -> 0}, Assumptions -> {t > 0 && t < 1/2 && z >= 1/4}])
df[t_,z_]=Sqrt[-(1/(-256 t^3+256 t^4-32 t z+64 t^2 (1+z)))]
fIndef[t_,z_]=Integrate[df[t,z],t]
f[z_]=Limit[fIndef[t,z],t->1/2,Direction->"FromBelow"] - Limit[fIndef[t,z],t->0,Direction->"FromAbove"]
g[z_,cMinus_,cPlus_] = Limit[w[t,z]/AsymtoticIntegrate[w[tt,z]*f[z],{z,cMinus,cPlus},tt->t],Assumptions->{cMinus>1/4}]

Whenever I run all this, I get g[z]=0

Your definition w[t_,z_] gives an error on Mathematica v12.2! Try w[t_, z_] =   1/(Integrate[rightFunc[t, z],       t] - (Integrate[rightFunc[t, z], t] /.        t -> 1/4) - (Integrate[leftFunc[t, z],         t] - (Integrate[leftFunc[t, z], t] /. t -> 0))) instead
